# Fields not showing when Editing Contact

Tags: drupal, contacts, contact-layout-editor

Contacts have multiple emails and phone number that appear on the Summary tab on the View page and can be edited there.  However when I select the edit button on a contact,  I get only one email address and no phone numbers listed.  The "add" links do nothing.  The Display preference are checked for email and phone. This was a new recent install. Current version of 5.23.3 and PHP version 7.3.15-3.  Any thought on why the additional email addresses and phone numbers are not showing on the edit page and why the"add" link on the edit page doesn't work?

Comment: Sounds like a javascript file isn't getting loaded. Check the browser dev console for errors.

Comment: Thanks that help lead to a PHP issue associate with the drupal theme

Comment: can you add as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An error was trace it back to a PHP issues with certain Drupal themes, specifically the one used with the drupal commerce module.  Although we are not using that module, We did have the admin theme for the module installed for the admin theme.  We changed that back to the standard admin theme and it appears to be working now.